# What's the dwell signals?

Tags: signal, multimeter, timing

Today When I was seeing [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter#Digital%20multimeters%20%28DMM%20or%20DVOM%29)(Digital multimeters (DMM or DVOM) part) I saw this part:

[image: figur1]

What does "automotive timing"? and What's the dwell signals? are these electronic concepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Automotive timing" refers to the ignition system of a gasoline engine - making sure that the spark happens at the right time.  The "dwell time" is the length of time that the distributor points are closed, applying power to the spark coil.

Comment: Just to clarify - pretty much any remotely modern automotive engine will have electronic ignition controlled by an ECU, with no contact points to wear or need adjustment - so the whole concept of 'dwell angle' etc is somewhat old-school and a bit of an anachronism - when appearing in the same context as 'surface mount technology' in that screenshot. . .